# Replace word starting with a

Tags: sed

I'm trying to understand sed. I have to replace every word starting with an a or A in a lipsum.txt with the word foobar. I started with `cat lipsum.txt | sed 's/\ba/foobar/g'` which already works, but it only replaces the a and not the entire word.

I read about using `cat lipsum.txt | sed 's/\ba\w+/foobar/g'` which targets the entire word. But it just doesn't replace anything. Same with `cat lipsum.txt | sed 's/\ba[A-Z]*/foobar/g'`, it just leaves the text untouched. What am I doing wrong?

Also if I substitute the a with "(a|A)" to be case-insensitive it also just stops working.

Comment: Where did you get the impression that sed understands those regular expressions from? None of those is a valid BRE.

Comment: Are there any words starting with `a` in you `lipsum.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `sed`, use

```
sed -i 's/\b[aA][[:alpha:]]*/foobar/g' file
```

Or,

```
sed -i 's/\b[aA][[:alnum:]]*/foobar/g' file
```

The `\b[aA]` matches a word starting with `a` or `A` and `[[:alnum:]]*` matches zero or more alphanumeric characters. `[[:alpha:]]*` matches zero or more letters.